# How to display formatted javascript code in webpage

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a blog and I want to display javascript code in a neat formatted way. Is there a way to it. I like to do it exactly the way stack overflow does including color. :)

Comment: Searching for JavaScript code highlighter give you multiple  libraries you can use.

Comment: Google `prettyPrint javascript`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this question is not about JavaScript coding, I am gonna answer it.
The highlighting you are looking for is called 'syntax highlighting'.
Here are my recommended JS libraries for easy syntax highlighting:-

- [highlight.JS](https://highlightjs.org/)
- [Prism.JS](https://prismjs.com/)
- [Prettify JS](https://github.com/google/code-prettify)

Hope I helped :-)

Answer (score -3):

Depending on the way your blog is written you can imagine just write a custom css class for the div where you have some code: Display a grey background with a dedicated font-family and size is pretty easy ;)

Comment: The OP is talking about syntax highlighting `I like to do it exactly the way stack overflow does including color.`.